# Extracting Pbf file with Docker

Tags: linux, docker, osrm

I am trying to follow simple instruction as given in the

> https://hub.docker.com/r/osrm/osrm-backend/

Instruction states as follow

download the data as

> wget http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/berlin-latest.osm.pbf

Pre-process the extract with the car profile and start a routing engine HTTP server on port 5000

> docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/berlin-latest.osm.pbf

The flag -v "${PWD}:/data" creates the directory /data inside the docker container and makes the current working directory "${PWD}" available there. The file /data/berlin-latest.osm.pbf inside the container is referring to "${PWD}/berlin-latest.osm.pbf" on the host.

but instead of Germany i changed it to India and download the data file

> wget http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india-latest.osm.pbf

and changed the docker command as

> sudo docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/india-latest.osm.pbf

and getting error :
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error' what():  boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/data/india-latest.osm.pbf"`

what I understand is docker is unable to extract the file due to some permission issue.
what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Followed the same steps as mentioned by you. I didn't received any error message.
You can give a try by removing sudo in front of your docker command.

Here is the output I see:

```
• • • docker run -t -v "${PWD}:/data" osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/india-latest.osm.pbf
[info] Parsed 0 location-dependent features with 0 GeoJSON polygons
[info] Using script /opt/car.lua
[info] Input file: india-latest.osm.pbf
[info] Profile: car.lua
[info] Threads: 8
[info] Parsing in progress..
[info] input file generated by osmium/1.8.0
[info] timestamp: 2020-08-21T20:42:02Z
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Found 3 turn restriction tags:
[info]   motorcar
[info]   motor_vehicle
[info]   vehicle
[info] Parse relations ...
[info] Parse ways and nodes ...
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Parsing finished after 129.569 seconds
[info] Raw input contains 126788006 nodes, 16092177 ways, and 7326 relations, 2201 restrictions
[info] Sorting used nodes        ... ok, after 0.693022s
[info] Erasing duplicate nodes   ... ok, after 0.097902s
[info] Sorting all nodes         ... ok, after 0.20617s
[info] Building node id map      ... ok, after 0.257703s
[info] Confirming/Writing used nodes     ... ok, after 1.89281s
[info] Writing barrier nodes     ... ok, after 0s
[info] Writing traffic light nodes     ... ok, after 0s
[info] Processed 39581602 nodes
[info] Sorting edges by start    ... ok, after 3.65041s
[info] Setting start coords      ... ok, after 2.50387s
[info] Sorting edges by target   ... ok, after 3.33254s
[info] Computing edge weights    ... ok, after 8.01501s
[info] Sorting edges by renumbered start ... ok, after 3.54458s
[info] Writing used edges       ... ok, after 1.30046s -- Processed 41373066 edges
[info] Writing way meta-data     ... ok, after 0.011832s -- Metadata contains << 3407420 entries.
[info] Sorting used ways         ... ok, after 0.010457s
[info] Collecting start/end information on 0 maneuver overrides...ok, after 0.039794s
[info] Collecting start/end information on 0 maneuver overrides...ok, after 0s
[info] Collecting start/end information on 2201 restrictions...ok, after 0.083874s
[info] Collecting start/end information on 2201 restrictions...ok, after 0.00159s
[info] writing street name index ... ok, after 0.002164s
[info] extraction finished after 155.758s
[info] Generating edge-expanded graph representation
[info] . 10% . 20% . 30% . 40% . 50% . 60% . 70% . 80% . 90% . 100%
[info] Node compression ratio: 0.148128
[info] Edge compression ratio: 0.185013
[info]  graph compression removed 3348686 annotations of 3407420 in 2.54008 seconds
[info] Find segregated edges in node-based graph ...
[info] ok, after 22.5332s
[info] Segregated edges count = 97299
[info] Writing nodes for nodes-based and edges-based graphs ...
[warn] Clipped 12 segment weights to 4194302
[info] Geometry successfully removed:
  compressed edges: 15309100
  compressed geometries: 82748654
  longest chain length: 8194
  cmpr ratio: 0.185007
  avg chain length: 5.40519
[info] Generating edge expanded nodes ... 
[info] . 10% . 20% . 30% . 40% . 50% . 60% . 70% . 80% . 90% . 100%
[info] Expanding via-way turn restrictions ... 
[info] . 10% . 20% . 30% . 40% . 50% . 60% . 70% . 80% . 90% . 100%
[info] Generated 14948742 nodes (236 of which are duplicates)  and 41373000 segments in edge-expanded graph
[info] Generating edge-expanded edges 
[info] [warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 631957, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=12.313006&mlon=75.129656
[warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 1025431, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=11.225002&mlon=72.773843
[warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 1025431, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=11.225002&mlon=72.773843
[warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 1025431, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=11.225002&mlon=72.773843
[warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 1025431, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=11.225002&mlon=72.773843
.[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
 10% [warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 4318270, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=9.949453&mlon=77.181601
.[warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 7481554, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=11.488963&mlon=73.002006
 20% . 30% . 40% . 50% .[warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 22139276, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=15.541327&mlon=77.926129
 60% . 70% .[warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 31183234, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=16.298204&mlon=81.05196
 80% . 90% .[warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 38391257, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=28.610931&mlon=77.052052
[warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 38392328, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=30.720227&mlon=76.677209
[warn] Turn is a u turn but not turning to the first connected edge of the intersection. Node ID: 39135596, OSM link: http://www.openstreetmap.org/?zoom=18&mlat=23.402787&mlon=81.358654

[info] Sorting and writing 0 maneuver overrides...
[info] done.
[info] Renumbering turns
[info] Writing 0 conditional turn penalties...
[info] Generated 41373000 edge based node segments
[info] Node-based graph contains 14830339 edges
[info] Edge-expanded graph ...
[info]   contains 30138979 edges
[info] Timing statistics for edge-expanded graph:
[info] Renumbering edges: 0.499508s
[info] Generating nodes: 5.43434s
[info] Generating edges: 45.995s
[info] Generating guidance turns 
[info] . 10% . 20% . 30% . 40% . 50% . 60% . 70% . 80% . 90% .
[info] done.
[info] Created 119 entry classes and 19951 Bearing Classes
[info] Handled: 51 of 3324 lanes: 1.5343 %.
[info] Assigned 33989015 turn instruction types:
[info]   new name: 483158 (1.42%)
[info]   continue: 1414398 (4.16%)
[info]   turn: 14280460 (42.01%)
[info]   merge: 26879 (0.08%)
[info]   on ramp: 11842 (0.03%)
[info]   off ramp: 10722 (0.03%)
[info]   fork: 131054 (0.39%)
[info]   end of road: 6390775 (18.80%)
[info]   notification: 618 (0.00%)
[info]   enter roundabout: 11530 (0.03%)
[info]   enter and exit roundabout: 1149 (0.00%)
[info]   enter rotary: 1176 (0.00%)
[info]   enter and exit rotary: 126 (0.00%)
[info]   enter roundabout turn: 2333 (0.01%)
[info]   (noturn): 328976 (0.97%)
[info]   (suppressed): 10856840 (31.94%)
[info]   roundabout: 28 (0.00%)
[info]   exit roundabout: 12393 (0.04%)
[info]   rotary: 9 (0.00%)
[info]   exit rotary: 1258 (0.00%)
[info]   exit roundabout turn: 2362 (0.01%)
[info]   (stay on roundabout): 15433 (0.05%)
[info]   (sliproad): 5496 (0.02%)
[info] Assigned 33989015 turn instruction modifiers:
[info]   uturn: 1376359 (4.05%)
[info]   sharp right: 481487 (1.42%)
[info]   right: 9817870 (28.89%)
[info]   slight right: 626400 (1.84%)
[info]   straight: 10569160 (31.10%)
[info]   slight left: 631180 (1.86%)
[info]   left: 10001525 (29.43%)
[info]   sharp left: 485034 (1.43%)
[info] Guidance turn annotations took 37.1287s
[info] Writing Intersection Classification Data
[info] ok, after 0.157749s
[info] Writing Turns and Lane Data...
[info] ok, after 0.105888s
[info] Saving edge-based node weights to file.
[info] Done writing. (0.101336)
[info] Computing strictly connected components ...
[info] Found 23696 SCC (6 large, 23690 small)
[info] SCC run took: 1.06626s
[info] Building r-tree ...
[info] Constructing r-tree of 41373000 segments build on-top of 39581602 coordinates
[info] finished r-tree construction in 6.08963 seconds
[info] Writing edge-based-graph edges       ... 
[info] ok, after 8.46229s
[info] Processed 30138979 edges
[info] Expansion: 211195 nodes/sec and 79762 edges/sec
[info] To prepare the data for routing, run: ./osrm-contract "/data/india-latest.osrm"
[info] RAM: peak bytes used: 10818285568
```